# Sort array based on intermediate model's attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, foreach, vuex-orm

I have three models (I am using Vue/Vuex-ORM on the frontend). `Category`, `CategoryItem` and `Item`.

I'm able to fetch an array of categories, and within each category is an array of items. An intermediate join model defines the relationships of these two models, and I am able to access as such:

```
// array of categories, each category has array of items
const categories = Category.query().where('pack_id', this.selectedPack.id).with('items').get();

categories.map(category => {
    category.items.forEach(item => {
        console.log('item.pivot: ', item.pivot); // pivot refers to join model
        // how to order items based on item.pivot?
    })
})
```

Within the `.forEach`, I can access the join model with `item.pivot`. What I am looking to do however, is sort each category's items based on `item.pivot.position`.

I started going down a path where the first line inside of the `.map` I defined a new empty array, and would then theoretically push in a new value based on whether the position was higher or lower, but I couldn't quite wrap my head around how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well just my luck. A half hour after posting this question, I figure it out! Here was what I did, in case anyone is curious.

```
categories() {
    const categories = Category.query().where('pack_id', this.selectedPack.id).with('items').get();

    categories.forEach(category => category.items.sort(this.compare));
    return cats;
}

compare(a, b) {
    let comparison = 0;
    if (a.pivot.position > b.pivot.position) comparison = 1;
    else if (a.pivot.position < b.pivot.position) comparison = -1;
    return comparison;
},
```